# Axon implicitly instantiate another aggregate using paramless constructor

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design, aggregate, event-sourcing, axon

I'm just wondering why Axon implicitly instantiate another aggregate. This behavior causes multiple event handling and I don't think this overhead is expected.
Having this endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("ship")
public void shipOrder(@RequestBody Product product) {
        String orderId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new PlaceOrderCommand(orderId, product.getName()));
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new ConfirmOrderCommand(orderId));
}
```

and following aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
public class Order {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String orderId;
    private boolean orderConfirmed;

    @CommandHandler
    public Order(PlaceOrderCommand command) {
        System.out.println("Calling COMMAND constructor");
        apply(new OrderPlacedEvent(command.getOrderId(), command.getProduct()));
    }

    protected Order() {
        System.out.println("Calling PARAMLESS constructor");
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(ConfirmOrderCommand command) {
        apply(new OrderConfirmedEvent(command.getOrderId()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderPlacedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> Handling OrderPlacedEvent: " + this);
        this.orderId = event.getOrderId();
        orderConfirmed = false;
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderConfirmedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> Handling OrderConfirmedEvent: " + this);
        orderConfirmed = true;
    }
}
```

After calling endpoint once I'm getting this log:

```
Calling COMMAND constructor
>>>>>> Handling OrderPlacedEvent: Order@3eecb9e2
Calling PARAMLESS constructor
>>>>>> Handling OrderPlacedEvent: Order@cd10277
>>>>>> Handling OrderConfirmedEvent: Order@cd10277
```

As you can see OrderPlacedEvent is called twice, along with constructor without parameters. Anyone know why I'm experiencing following behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is correct and expected when you use Event Sourcing. In Event Sourcing, whenever you send a command to an aggregate, it will first load all previous events to hydrate the aggregate and determine it's current state. These event are your source of thruth. The current state of the aggregate is, aside from some exceptions, not stored.

As such, in general you should make sure you only use your `EventSourcingHandler` in your aggregate to populate its state.

Note that once a system grows a lot, an aggregate could potentially have a large number of events that will need to be read. Should this occurs, there is some optimization you can do, by storing a snapshot of your aggregate (it's current state) after every `n` events. This way you won't have to load more than `n` events.

Comment: So, whenever I create aggregate via command using 1-param-constructor, Axon is creating an empty instance and then apply all events even though there are no events in store? Moreover - it is constructor so I think it should be obvious that this aggregate has no event any in store yet.

Comment: Axon uses the constructor with the command argument (`PlaceOrderCommand` in your case) the first time that command is received and when the aggregate will be created. Nothing is read form the event store yet. On any subsequent command, the first command no longer exists. As such, the no args constructor is used to created the object, and all events are replayed form the eventstore.

Comment: I think I finally understand how it works. Assume adding third command, then third aggregate instance will be created (using empty constructor) and all subsequent events will be handled. I was pretty sure Axon reuses aggregate instance loaded in memory and just apply only new events. Great, thanks for full explanation!